# How do I restore my saved session? (Clicked save session - okay - asked for project name - then GONE)

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm new to R-Studio.  I did a bunch of work, followed some tutorials.  I saved my session, it then asked for a project directory name (I never selected "new project"), and then it auto-reloaded, and all my work is gone.  The save session says okay before that project name dialog came up by itself (automatically, immediately after the save.  I haven't touched anything since then.  How do I get my work back?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer at community.rstudio.com

I did a search for .RData files, and found one in My Documents. (Windows 10.)  I opened this file with R-Studio (with R-Studio not already running).  I then clicked on the History tab, and all of my past commands are there.

I have saved that history, and I can reload it into the newly created project.